# how to pass the ’ Environmental Variables’ and ‘Global Variables’ from Jenkins using postman(newman) – Execute Windows batch command (Re-open)

Tags: jenkins

how to pass the ’ Environmental Variables’ and ‘Global Variables’ from Jenkins using postman(newman) – Execute Windows batch command

how to pass the ’ Environmental Variables’ and ‘Global Variables’ from Jenkins using postman(newman) – Execute Windows batch command

Comment: Thanks for your inputs; Well, I can execute in the local machine with cmd(command line) with success. The issue is how would I give the -g test.postman_globals.json -e Test.postman_environment.json in the JENKINS job which is  Freestyle Project > Add Build step is: -  'Execute Windows batch command NOT the CMD..!

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman

Here you can see all the supported commandline flags, so for your question

```
npm run collection.json --global-var "user1=testuser" --global-var "user1=testuser" --env-var "user1=envuser"
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs; Well, I can execute in the local machine with cmd(command line) with success. The issue is how would I give the -g test.postman_globals.json -e Test.postman_environment.json in the JENKINS job which is Freestyle Project > Add Build step is: - 'Execute Windows batch command NOT the CMD..!

Comment: @poornapragna execute batch is exactly cmd , you are telling to run windows cmd comments on a target machine ,